# Add product according to category in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new in Django. I want to add product against the category which I select, but I don't know how can I do that. I select the category and add product but nothing happened. I don't know how can I do this. Thank you in advance

Model.py

```
    class Product(models.Model):
          category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
          price = models.IntegerField()
```

view.py

```
  class SelectCategory(TemplateView):

        template_name = 'purchase/selectCategory.html'

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            categories = CategoryModel.objects.all()
            args = {'categories': categories}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)

       def post(self, request):
           try:
              data = self.request.POST.get
              categoryId = ProductModel.category['category.id'].id
              product = ProductModel(
                 category_id=data(categoryId),
                 name=data('name'),
                 price=data('price')
              )
              product.save()
              return redirect('menu')
         except Exception as e:
              return HttpResponse('failed{}'.format(e))
```

Template

```
 {% extends 'auth/home.html' %}

 {% block content %}
   <form method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <label> Select Category
         <select name="Select Category">
           <option disabled="disabled" selected> Select Category</option>
              {% for category in categories %}

              <option value={{ category.id }}>
                  {{ category.name }}
              </option>
              {% endfor %}
        </select>
     </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Select">
  </form>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
     <label for="name">Name
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Product name">
    </label>
    <label for="price">Price
         <input type="number" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Enter Price of Product">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    <button><a href="{% url 'menu' %}">Menu</a></button>

</form>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a Django form?

Comment: because after using form it's difficult to apply CSS that's why i use simple HTML

Comment: @waqarahmad See [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/), it is a great package to customize rendering of forms. **Never** render the forms **completely** manually. Also see [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @waqarahmad: A Django form can be customized further. and you can render parts manually that are difficult, but a form is not only for HTML rendering, but also to clean (and save) the data in the database. So you can even decide to keep manually rendering the form, but use it in the `post` function to parse the data.

Comment: Ok i will try but now how can i fix my issue at this time

Comment: @waqarahmad firstly you have two separate forms here, make them one form. secondly `data(categoryId)` does not make much sense, I believe you want to get the selected category? It should be `data("Select Category")` (that is the name attribute you set on your select) (Don't know if that will work never used spaces in name attributes before)

Answer (score 0):

Get the category instance first using data selected category id and then push that instance to as a parameter to productmodel.

```
def post(self, request):
           try:
              data = self.request.POST.get
              categoryObj= CategoryModel.objects.get(I'd=data[])
              product = ProductModel(
                 category_id= categoryObj
                 name=data('name'),
                 price=data('price')
              )
              product.save()
              return redirect('menu')
         except Exception as e:
              return HttpResponse('failed{}'.format(e))
```

Comment: categoryobj = CategoryModel.objects.get(id=data['category.id']). i did this after select the category and add the product, it show error ' failed'method' object is not subscriptable '

Comment: Have you checked with data key is dic not tuple you have to use data[key] also can you share the screenshot of the error

Comment: i did data[SelectCategory]  but still same i error i get ' ' failed'method' object is not subscriptable ' '

Comment: The issue was in query 
categoryObj= CategoryModel.objects.get(I'd=data[])

the right one is 

categoryObj= self.request.GET.get('SelectCategory ').